# Send-MailMessage Argument Null or empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Can someone please help me figure this part out.

```
#Mail Configuration
$smtpUser = "email@domain.com"
$smtppass = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordAsPlainText" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($smtpuser, $smtppass)
$ToAddress = "toaddress@domain.com"
$FromAddress = "send@domain.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPPORT = "587"

$MailParam = @{
        To = $ToAddress
        From = $FromAddress
        Subject = $subject
        Body = $Mail
        SMTPServer = $SMTPServer
        Port = $SMTPPORT
        Credential = $pscred
        }
#Send Email
$GetChildItem = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp
if ($GetChildItem -ne $Null)
    {
    Write-Host "Backup Success"
    $subject = "$env:COMPUTERNAME SQL Backup Success"
    $Mail = "SQL Backup Succeded on the server, please see the attached report for more details"
    $attachment = $reportfile
    Send-MailMessage @MailParam -BodyAsHtml -usessl
   #Exit
    }
if ($GetChildItem -eq $Null)
    {
    Write-Host "Backup Failed"
    $subject = "$env:COMPUTERNAME SQL Backup Failed"
    $Mail = "SQL Backup Failed on the server, please see the attached report for more details"
    $attachment = $reportfile, $debuglog
    Send-MailMessage @MailParam -usessl -BodyAsHtml
    #Exit
    }
```

Now I don't think anything is wrong with the code above, I am no expert coder but I can pretty much copy and paste :) and take stuff from there to get it working for me.

The issue with the above code is that when run it, it doesn't work for the 1st time but when you run it again it works fine. The error you get the first time is

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
>   At C:\Users\Aasim\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:29 char:26
>   +         Send-MailMessage @MailParam -BodyAsHtml -usessl
>   +                          ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

I am not sure what the issue is and why it doesn't work only the first time but works every other subsequent time until you close and reopen the script.

Basically I am creating a SQL backup script that backs up databases to our Network Share and then emails me whether it was successful or not. so far the rest of the script works just fine.

Comment: just while posting this I realized that when $MailParam is called it does have $subject as null as $subject isn't defined until the end of the script. how do I fix this?

Comment: I guess i figured it out, instead of passing Subject and body in $MailParam i just replaced my Sen-MailMessage line to below. 
Send-MailMessage @MailParam -Subject $Subject -Body $Mail  -Attachments $attachment -BodyAsHtml -usessl

Comment: If you think others may run into a similar problem and you've found a solution that you think future readers may benefit from, please post it as an answer (which you can [self-accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours); otherwise, please consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your If and Else blocks, instead of creating a variable `$subject`, or `$Mail`, update the hashtable, `$MailParam`. Also, you seem to be missing the Attachment variable in your Send-`MailMessage`

```
if ($GetChildItem -eq $Null)
    {
    Write-Host "Backup Failed"
    $MailParam.Subject = "$env:COMPUTERNAME SQL Backup Failed"
    $MailParam.Body = "SQL Backup Failed on the server, please see the attached report for more details"
    $attachment = $reportfile, $debuglog
    Send-MailMessage @MailParam -usessl -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $attachment
    #Exit
    }
```